# Convert .csv into .txt with a specific length

Tags: vba, csv, text-files

I have a .csv file. I want to convert it into .txt file starting from line the A to the B (A, B are declared at the beginning). The .txt file supposed to have gaps " " instead of original semicolons. Moreover, the end of each copied row from the original .csv file should be indicated by a semicolon in the new .txt file (txt file is going to be used as an input matrix for Matlab).

Could you please help me with that?

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Vaclav

Comment: Why don't you save it as a .mat file rather than a .txt if it is going to be used by Matlab?

Comment: I'm using Excel2010 for VBA macros but I'm supper inexperienced with that... I've tried to search some threats hear at stackoverflow but I'm not really familiar with the routines.

I thought that using a .txt file is going to be more convenient since I will use several such "matrixes" for my matlab (I can then just copy+paste the content of the separate txt file as an input matrix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi if you locking for VBA code, maybe that could help you...

```
Sub csv2mat()
Dim Filename As String
Dim Filenamenew As String
Dim str As String
'Change the path to the Files and and create a txt file
Filename = "C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\as.csv"
Filenamenew = "C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\new.txt"
Open Filenamenew For Output As #2
Open Filename For Input As #1
Do While Not EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, str
    str = Replace(str, ";", """") & ";"
    Print #2, str
Loop
Close #1
Close #2
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Moosli. I think this is pretty much what I was looking for. cheers